# Could not display the updated model using modelForm in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to django. I am having trouble in displaying some updated data from django model to the html file. I have a delete and add button in the html which will add or remove records to django model. When I click on delete, at the beginning it displays all the records and I can delete the record. Second time when I click, I am getting the previously deleted item also in the list. How can I remove it? I only wanted to display the current items from the model using modelForm. Following is my files:

> form.py

```
class deleteFileChannelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    curChannels = getAllChannel('file')
    j = 0
    channelList = []
    for item in curChannels:
        tempTuple = (j, item)
        channelList.insert(j, tempTuple)
        j += 1
    DeleteChannelName = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control',
        }), choices=channelList)

    class Meta:
        model = deleteFileChannel
        fields = ('DeleteFileChannelName',)
```

> model.py

```
class deleteFileChannel(models.Model):
    owaDeleteFileChannelName = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owaDeleteFileChannelName
```

> view.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
        deleteForm = deleteFileChannelForm(request.POST)   
        if  deleteForm.is_valid():
            data = request.POST.copy()
            deleteChannelid = int(data.get('DeleteFileChannelName'))
            deleteChannelName =  channelList[deleteChannelid][1]
            FileChannel.objects.get(FileChannelName=deleteChannelName).delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fileChannel', ))
        else:
            print("Invalid form")
    else:
        formEditChannel = deleteFileChannelForm()
        return render(request, 'Channels/fileChannel.html',{'formAdd':formAddChannel,'formDelete': formEditChannel,
                                                               'channels':allFileChannel})
```

> html file

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" >
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Select channel to delete.</h5>
                            {{formDelete.DeleteFileChannelName}}
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer" id="modFooter2">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Delete">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're populating the choices for the `DeleteChannelName` field using code that you've defined at the class level in `deleteFileChannelForm`. Code defined at the class level *will execute once* at import time. This means that the choices won't change once they've been populated.

To fix, you can populate the choices each time an instance of the form is created, in the form's `__init__()` method. For example:

```
class deleteFileChannelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    DeleteChannelName = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control',
        }), choices=())  # Empty choices here

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Retrieve the channels
        curChannels = getAllChannel('file')
        j = 0
        channelList = []
        for item in curChannels:
            tempTuple = (j, item)
            channelList.insert(j, tempTuple)
            j += 1

        # Populate the choices
        self.fields['DeleteChannelName'].choices = channelList

    class Meta:
        model = deleteFileChannel
        fields = ('DeleteFileChannelName',)
```

Comment: this solution fixed my error. Thank you very much for your help.